# Two websites cannot talk to each other in docker local

Tags: php, docker

I have a single docker container that has two PHP driven websites inside it. When I spin up the docker container with docker-compose up, I can navigate to them independently just fine.

`http://website-A-local/` &  `http://website-B-local/`  both work independently.

Working from website-B, when I try to do a PHP include to a file from website-A it fails, with no errors. It does nothing with no indication of what's wrong.

On website-B's index.php

```
<?php 
include('http://website-A-local/api/some-file.php');    
?>
```

However if I put website-A's api file on the live server and try it out, it loads fine on website-B local.

```
<?php 
include('https://website-A-production.com/api/some-file.php');
?>
```

How can we get PHP to include or get_file_contents between two websites running in the same docker container? They don't seem to know about each other although they can be navigated to independently in the browser without any issue.

```
Docker Compose file: 

    # Docker version
    version : "3"
    
    services :
    
      # Apache
      apache :
        build : '.\docker\apache\'  # this should point to where the Dockerfile exists for this container
        ports :                     # specifying host:container
          - 80:80
        volumes :                   # local filesystem:container filesystem
          - ./:/var/www/html/
    
      # PHP
      php :
        build : '.\docker\php\'
        environment:
          XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9003 remote_enable=1
        volumes :                   # local filesystem:container filesystem
          - ./:/var/www/html/
        links:
          - apache:epicor-web-local # Without this, wkhtmltopdf will not work since the php container has to make another request to create the pdf
        expose:
          - 9003
    
      # MySQL
      mysql :
        image : mysql:5.7.14
        ports :
          - 3305:3306               # local filesystem:container filesystem
        command: --lower_case_table_names=1
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: TestDB
        volumes :
          - ./docker/mysql/.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/.

  # PHPMyAdmin
  phpmyadmin :
    image : phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports :
      # It's okay to map this to 80 on container filesystem b/c each container has own set of ports
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql          # specify which container this needs to talk to
      - PMA_PORT=3306           # specify port of the above container
    depends_on:
      - mysql                   # will not spin up phpmyadmin if mysql fails to build
```

Comment: I would do a local include then if possible, with the local path of the file you want to include, since it's the same container it should be available. It might be a dns issue when resolving the domain, your hosts know the domain but the container perhaps does not know them, or it might know only one domain but not the other one

Comment: Using include for that is an odd choice - file_get_contents or curl would be more appropriate. This _sounds_ like the domains do not resolve - are you using docker compose, if so please add the compose file to the question. If you're not how are website-a-local and website-b-local to know of each other?

Comment: `two websites running in the same docker container` - if they are in the same container why are they talking to each other over http?

Comment: @AD7six I'm trying include and get_file_contents both (just grasping at straws). It does sound like they can't resolve each other in DNS (and thus that is my question)

Yes I used docker-compose and I've added the file.

Comment: They will be talking to each other over http when they go live. The live server doesn't use Docker.

Comment: I suggest to replace the `php` container with a `website-a` container and a `website-b` (adding `container_name: website-a` `container_name: website-b` to docker compose may be necessary) you can then reference each of them from within the container as `http://website-a` `http://website-b`. If you are not deploying the sites to the same host/container - doing that locally is a source of confusion. It's still weird to use `include` to communicate between websites like this.